# How would I test a param is getting modified in a RSpec controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am setting a user through modifying the params instead of creating a hidden_field in the form. As far as I understand, this is a more secure way of handling mass-assignment.

```
  def update
    @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])

    #this is the important part
    if params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].present?
      params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
        value[1].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
      end
    end
    #end the important part

    respond_to do |format|
      if @exercise.update_attributes(params[:exercise])
        format.html { redirect_to_back_or_default @exercise, notice: "Exercise was successfully updated." }
        format.mobile { redirect_to @exercise, notice: 'Exercise was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.mobile { redirect_to @exercise, notice: "#{@exercise.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}" }
        format.json { render json: @exercise.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my spec I have the following:

```
describe "with log_entry_attributes" do
  it "updates log_entries_attributes and sets user" do
    exercise = FactoryGirl.create(:exercise)
    log_entry = FactoryGirl.build(:log_entry)
    exercise.log_entries << log_entry
    exercise.save
    controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
    put :update, :id => exercise.id, :exercise => FactoryGirl.build(:exercise, "log_entries_attributes" => {":0" => {"reps" => "5", "weight" => "5"}}).attributes.symbolize_keys
    assigns(:exercise).log_entries.first.user.should eq(@user)
  end
end
```

I get `undefined method user for nil:NilClass`. I think I know why I get undefined method user. There's just no way to get the association through assigns. I'm not sure how to test that the user_id is being set properly through the current_user. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with mocked object:

```
exercise = double "exercise"
Exercise.should_receive(:find).and_return(exercise)
```

and test with:

```
exercise.should_receive(:update_attributes).with(correct_params)
```

Comment: But how do I test that user_id is actually getting set through the current_user? That's what the test should be, no?

Comment: Well, send corrupted params and check that correct_params is what you expect.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. Since it's being modified outside of the params, during the update_attributes it should expect it to look the way I want after it's modified. Great. I got it to pass! Thank you!